# Please review / improve my .htaccess non-www to www rewrite plan

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

Running WP multisite with client's able to use their own domain name.  Works great - except the case where client does not use my nameservers and simply has an A record pointing to the WP static IP address.

This happens sometimes when the client DNS has a ton of service records (e.g. Office 365), it is just safer to leave DNS there.

When I control DNS, I can alias non-WWW to WWW, which makes WP multisite happy.  When client is just using the A record pointer, the WP multisite trips on the incoming non-WWW request and lands at the sign-up page for the multisite.  It really needs the 'www', to work right (unfortunately).

I solve for each client by doing this in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

which so far seems to work great.

**Questions:**

1. Does this method seem reasonable?
2. Is there a better way to handle this, given the issue I am seeing?
3. If I wanted to make this re-write generic to handle any incoming domain (as long as that domain **does not** include my base multisite domain name!) -- could someone show me how to form the condition/rule?

I kind of like hard-coding the actual domain because that guarantees nothing else gets touched, but I would imagine once I have a few hundred of these it may become silly.

Comment: What do you mean by "alias non-WWW to WWW"? The client presumably has an A record on `www.example.com` as well as `example.com` - presumably the _client_ could resolve this by only having an A record on `www.example.com` (but maybe undesirable to not have `example.com` resolvable)?

Comment: In this case Office 365 tells the customer to A record `example.com` to static IP but to CNAME `www.example.com` to `example.com`  -- at that point I get the non-www incoming thus the .htaccess requirement.  I don't think you can do the opposite (CNAME everything to `example.com`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I control DNS, I can alias non-WWW to WWW, which makes WP multisite happy.

Not quite sure what you mean by "alias" here, but presumably you need to implement some kind of canonical non-WWW to WWW redirect even when you control the DNS?

> 1. Does this method seem reasonable?

So, this type of redirect does seem reasonable. Creating additional VirtualHost's would seem to be a lot more work. (?)

> 2. Is there a better way to handle this, given the issue I am seeing?

As mentioned in comments, the client could set an `A` record on `www.example.com` instead and only have the site accessible from the `www` subdomain. But this is probably undesirable. So, either way, you are going to have to resolve the domain canonicalisation at your end, which is going to involve a 301 redirect.

> 3. If I wanted to make this re-write generic to handle any incoming domain (as long as that domain does not include my base multisite domain name!) -- could someone show me how to form the condition/rule?

In your server config, you could do something like the following, to handle *any* domain, but exclude the *base* domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^base-domain-to-exclude\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If the `HTTP_HOST` does not start with `www.` then redirect to the same *host* with `www.` prepended.

You also don't need the `<IfModule>` wrapper here. You already know that mod_rewrite is enabled on your server, but even so, the `<IfModule>` wrapper is only required if your site is intended to "work" without mod_rewrite.

Comment: thanks - 'alias' means via AWS Route 53 I can use an S3 bucket as a pointer for an alias record in DNS, to point `example.com` to `www.example.com`.  That's how I normally handle getting all traffic to www.  Two questions about the generic rewrite:  (a) I think it will rewrite the base domain; I need to be able to exclude the base WP domain completely - so need some sort of "if domain is xyz then skip this rule"...and (b) right now the mapped domains are http but would this rule handle https as well?  Thanks again for taking the time to answer.

Comment: (a) Sorry, forget to mention about the base domain - thought you might have wanted to canonicalise the base domain as well. I've updated the code to exclude the _base_ domain - just an additional `RewriteCond` directive. (b) To redirect to HTTPS, just change the `RewriteRule` substitution from `http` to `https`. However, at that time you'd probably want to implement an explicit http to https redirect as well.

Comment: Thanks!  Final question on this answer:  You eliminated the caret ^ ('starts with') from the RewriteRule - is there a specific reason you don't use it?  Or since the string starts with `http://` the 'starts with' directive isn't really needed?  (I am an htaccess newbie as you can tell...)

Comment: In the pattern `^(.*)`, the caret `^` is superfluous. (Nothing to do with `http://`. The `$1` is a _backreference_ to the string matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_.) The pattern `.*` already matches _everything_, so the pattern `^(.*)` is _everything_ from the start, which is the same as _everything_! And is no more _efficient_. (It is common to see `^(.*)$` - probably through mindless copy/paste or because that's the way they've always done it - but the anchors `^` and `$` are entirely redundant here and simply add visual complexity, hampering readability IMO.)

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a separate virtualhost for `example.com` that simply serves a 301 sending the client to `www.example.com`.